# PHP - mkdir with wrong owner

Tags: php, .htaccess, mkdir, ownership, chown

I have an simple PHP script that creates a folder and then copies certain files into it. The folder (and copied files) have all 755 permissions. The problem is, it sets the user as Apache.
Now I can not delete or change permissions through FTP. I can only 'reset ownership' in my DirectAdmin. There I can see the user changes from "Apache" to "matthdc58".

How can I let PHP create a folder with "matthdc58" as user? I tried `chown()` - failed:

```
Warning: chown() [function.chown]: Operation not permitted in /home/matthdc58/domains/hiddendomain.com/public_html/Home.php on line 78

Warning: chown() [function.chown]: Operation not permitted in /home/matthdc58/domains/hiddendomain.com/public_html/Home.php on line 79

Warning: chown() [function.chown]: Operation not permitted in /home/matthdc58/domains/hiddendomain.com/public_html/Home.php on line 80

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/matthdc58/domains/hiddendomain.com/public_html/Home.php:78) in /home/matthdc58/domains/hiddendomain.com/public_html/Home.php on line 90
```

I also tried (seemed to solve others' problems) `php_flag safe_mode off` in my .htaccess, to no prevail.

---

My whole PHP script:

```
$dirtocreate = 'userdata/'.$_SESSION['uname'];
$oldumask = umask(0); 
mkdir($dirtocreate, 0755);
umask($oldumask);

copy('img/100x100.png', $dirtocreate.'/100x100.png');   
copy('img/64x64.png', $dirtocreate.'/64x64.png');   

//Verify correct owner
chown($dirtocreate, 'matthdc58');
chown($dirtocreate.'/100x100.png', 'matthdc58');
chown($dirtocreate.'/64x64.png', 'matthdc58');

//Verify correct permissions, just to be sure               
chmod($dirtocreate,0755);
chmod($dirtocreate.'/100x100.png',0755);        
chmod($dirtocreate.'/64x64.png',0755);
```

---

**So, just to clarify:**

- My PHP script sets the owner of the new folder to "Apache".
- The PHP
  script fails to change the owner to "matthdc58".
- Now, I can not edit
  the folder through FTP, since the owner is "Apache".
- I can only restore ownership through DirectAdmin with the "Restore Ownership"
  button.

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have chmodded and chowned your directory: /home/matthdc58/domains/hiddendomain.com/public_html/ to your username. :)

Comment: DirectAdmin says `/public_html/` has a UID and a GID set to 'matthdc58', if that's what you mean. (UID is the owner, right?)

Comment: Yeah. It says chown() is not permitted. You on a VPS? If so, I can definitely tell you how to fix this.

Comment: I don't believe so. I use webhosting from [Versio](http://www.versio.nl), but I can't really find it easily. (Any way to find out?)

Comment: What hosting plan do you have? I'll check.

Comment: Uhm... [Starter NL](http://www.versio.nl/webhosting.php) - *blush* - I couldn't find it in the FAQ.(+1 for the effort)

Comment: By the looks of it, you don't have server root access. I don't think you'll be able to use chown() - try without it, maybe it'll chown it to you anyway. :)

Comment: Without `chown()`, the error of course dissappears, but I'm left with my original problem. I can not edit/delete the folder through FTP, unless I `restore ownership` through DirectAdmin first.

Comment: I would've thought, the creator is added to the ownership permissions automatically.

Comment: So... PHP forces the owner to "Apache" and I can only **manually** - *sigh* - change it (back) to "matthdc58" in order to edit them through FTP? (Or I'd have to set the permissions of the folder to `777`, but as I've understood, this isn't safe). Isn't there any other solution?

Comment: But I already use 755 (as can be seen). 744 would remove the execute permission. What would it solve? :)

Comment: Ah, right. 755 works. But not sure why chown() won't work, contact your host. :) Ask them to give you permission.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! I'll post/reply as soon as I get an answer

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be related to the version of PHP I was using.
*At recommendation of my host, Versio,* I changed the version of PHP by adding

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
AddHandler x-httpd-php54 .php
</FilesMatch>
```

to my .htaccess file.

---

I  don't think this is relevant for others, as this had to do with the rights, but you can always try.
*Again,* thanks to @LeSamAdmin for helping me out!